# Setting up Spring Data JPA with AD Service Principal in application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, azure-service-principal

So as per documentation in Azure:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource;

public class AADServicePrincipal {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String principalId = "1846943b-ad04-4808-aa13-4702d908b5c1"; // Replace with your AAD service principal ID.
        String principalSecret = "..."; // Replace with your AAD principal secret.

        SQLServerDataSource ds = new SQLServerDataSource();
        ds.setServerName("aad-managed-demo.database.windows.net"); // Replace with your server name
        ds.setDatabaseName("demo"); // Replace with your database
        ds.setAuthentication("ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal");
        ds.setAADSecurePrincipalId(principalId);
        ds.setAADSecurePrincipalSecret(principalSecret);

        try (Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
                Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT SUSER_SNAME()")) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("You have successfully logged on as: " + rs.getString(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We can use this to create a Data Source that can connect via AD Service Principal to SQL Server, and insert it as a bean I believe as:

```
@Bean
@Primary
DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
    String principalId = "1846943b-ad04-4808-aa13-4702d908b5c1"; // Replace with your AAD service principal ID.
    String principalSecret = "..."; // Replace with your AAD principal secret.
    
    SQLServerDataSource ds = new SQLServerDataSource();
    ds.setServerName("aad-managed-demo.database.windows.net"); // Replace with your server name
    ds.setDatabaseName("demo"); // Replace with your database
    ds.setAuthentication("ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal");
    ds.setAADSecurePrincipalId(principalId);
    ds.setAADSecurePrincipalSecret(principalSecret);
    return ds;
}
```

But what I am looking for is -
Can we configure this whole thing via YAML/application.properties so that it gets auto configured with Data JPA ?
If not, can the above process work ?

Answer (score 0):

The following configurations work for me.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://<host>:<port>;database=<database name>;authentication=ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal;
    username: <your AAD service principal ID>
    password: <your AAD principal secret>
```

According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16), my configurations can be used from [JDBC Driver 10.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc) onwards.